# Massive 404 attack in WordPress Site

Tags: php, wordpress, google-crawlers

Google crawler reported massive 404 pages on my WordPress website like below urls:

- http://example.com/adidas-yeezy-750-online-atmos-hXfBKn.htm
- http://example.com/yeezy-boost-350-sand-release-date-used-vans-s8cPbh.htm

Is this some type of hack?

Comment: 404 means "Not found" which could indicate that something is indeed wrong with your site **if** those URL's used to exist, but they might've been there always, google telling you that they are there isn't a indication of an' attack no.

Comment: There is no chance to crawl this type url in my website. I doubts if hackers are injecting some code to my website to generate these type of url. It is seems like these urls are related to some ads and all of these urls have some common format.

Comment: Then it might be a faulty URL somewhere, google should tell you where the URL's are coming from, but no, it's most likely not a attack, but more likely just a set of wrong URL's

Comment: Yes, I can see the url from where it is "Linked From". I go to that url and checked the page source could not find my 404 url there.

Answer (score 0):

Hack. Yes a possibility. Not too long ago [wordpress xml-rpc exploit](https://blog.sucuri.net/2015/10/brute-force-amplification-attacks-against-wordpress-xmlrpc.html) was found , After the attacker has access to your wordpress installation, it hosts malicious websites on your installation, but for a limited time. After that the router changes the hosting content to some other installation.

Does your webserver acess logs look like [this](https://gist.github.com/vishwakarma09/60dcddba6ce539ffaf3f)

Also, you can refer to [this](https://gist.github.com/vishwakarma09/6669487bf307edef8959) reply I framed for aws team when my wordpress installation was compromised

Now, try identifying the symptoms. Check your CPU and networking usage as well. A peak usage in that time-frame indicates that your installation was being used as bandwidth+cpu resource for hosting malicious code+xmlrpc code exploit on other installations.